# Objective C - UIImagePickerController customize bottom navigation

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I customize the button and background color of UIImagePickerController's bottom navigation?

In the image below, it would be the "cancel" & "choose" button and the background.

Thank you,
Tee

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do any customizations to default controls. You can have complete customized view (preview view) if you set `showsCameraControls` to NO.